# Reusing the same value in a SQL query

Tags: mysql

I am trying to use the same value from a SELECT statement multiple times.
The beginning of my query looks like this:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM `friends` WHERE (`Friend1ID`=value OR `Friend2ID`=value))...
```

`value` should be the result of a SELECT query, say:

```
SELECT `ID` FROM `users` WHERE `name`='daniel'
```

I could use the same SELECT statement twice, but are there any other possibilities that would make the query "cleaner"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are simply trying to get a list of friends with an associated user name of 'daniel' then you can use an `INNER JOIN`.

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM  
    friends
    INNER JOIN users ON users.ID=friends.friends1ID OR users.ID=friends.friends2ID

WHERE
    users.name='daniel'
```